# Compile .cpp file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community and I wanted to compile a .cpp file directly, instead of creating a project or manually compile outside the program.
I was able to add an External Tool that executes "cl.exe" on the current item, but  it says "fatal error C1034: iostream: no include path set".
Running "vcvars32" and then "cl filename.cpp" worked on the Windows Command Prompt, but I was only able to execute one of the commands on VS, and not both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

Create a script called compile.cmd

In this same folder, create a file named compile.cmd with the following contents (modified for your environment)

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
cd %1
cl.exe %2
```

Note the `call` keyword in the script. This enables the script to keep running after it invokes another script.

Now create the external tool in Visual Studio and direct it to run your compile.bat file.  Specify absolute path to this compile.bat file in the tool window for "Command".  And specify the exact path of the folder for "Initial Directory".

Disable "Close on Exit"

[image]

Result when running the command:

[image]

Comment: But to use that, I have to change manually the filename for each program.
Isn't there a way of changing the filename (after "cl.exe") according to each one?

Comment: Also, how can I execute a file on Visual Studio console right after I compile it?

Comment: I think you are trying to insert a square peg into a round hole.  That is, whatever you are doing, you are doing it "the hard way". (Also known as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166177)).  Perhaps if you elaborate on what you are really trying to accomplish, I can give a better suggestion.

Comment: You can also add a call to "main.exe" to the end of the script that you launch.

Comment: But to answer your immediate question, you can set `$(ItemPath)` in `Arguments` edit box in the External Tools Window.  You can reference it in your script as %1.  Modify the script to be invoke `cl.exe %1` instead of the hardcoded main.cpp

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you can do what you want.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you in the first place. Besides that, I may have complicated my issue. What I aimed to do was to edit a single C++ fiile and directly execute it on VS, instead of compiling it externaly